# NLP: How to train a spaCy NER Model using GoldParse objects

Tags: pandas, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train a spaCy NER model using GoldParse objects. This is what I have done:

*Adding extra labels to NER model*

```
add_ents = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', 'G1'] # sample labels

# Create a pipe if it does not exist
if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner") 
    nlp.add_pipe(ner)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

for e in add_ents:
    ner.add_label(e)
```

*Training the NER Model*

```
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]
model = None # Since we training a fresh model not a saved model
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train ner
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
    for i in range(20):
        loss = {}
        nlp.update(X, y,  sgd=optimizer, drop=0.0, losses=loss)
        print("Loss: ", loss)
```

Here X is a list of Doc objects and y is a list of corresponding GoldParse objects. While executing I am running into the following error:

```
nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.update()

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser._init_gold_batch()

ner.pyx in spacy.syntax.ner.BiluoPushDown.preprocess_gold()

ner.pyx in spacy.syntax.ner.BiluoPushDown.lookup_transition()

ValueError: 'A1' is not in list
```

I tried searching for the solution but couldn't find anything relevant. Is there a way to fix this issue?